# How to create a customized navigation drawer menu as shown in image

Tags: android

[image]

I want to create a custom Fragment navigation menu without `AppBar`. I want a button to call `DrawerLayout`. When a button is clicked it calls `DrawerLayout` because I use `Fragments`.

I want a menu button with a notification badge as shown below in 1 image, then when a menu is selected in `NavigationDrawer` it goes to a `Fragment` where the drawer menu icon is replaced by a back arrow.

[image: img]

Comment: What you exactly want?

Comment: where is image...

Answer (score 0):

Inside the activity of page in with you want this back button firstly initialize your Action bar and then use this inside **oncreate** of that activity

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

this will help.